# VSCode snipet for multi level arrays

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode if I can do `ul>li*3>div` I'll get:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I do much with nested arrays:

```
  const array = [
    [1], 
    [2], 
    [3], 
    [4],
    ...
  ]
```

How can I write the snippet to make this easily instead of `[` and `]` so many times? Such as `a>a*3`

Comment: you can use the Hyper Snips extension and use a regex prefix that recognizes the formats you want to use and program the snippet in JavaScript, and then use a formatter to format the inserted block, Emmet does the same thing for HTML files